# Adding a row in excel 2013 to a set of data is making another set of formulas incorrect

Tags: vba, excel

What I have is a back end of data on a sheet in excel, this back end is just 1 column of data in column A.

I have 5 sheets that have to reference this data quite simply with the formula:

```
='Sheet1'!A2
='Sheet1'!A3
```

etc etc

When I insert a new row of data into sheet 1 it messes the formulas up on the other sheets - its as if the other sheets cannot read that a new row of data has been entered in sheet 1. So as an example, say I add a new row in between A2 and A3 in sheet 1, the other sheets do not pick this up and keep the same data in although now instead of

```
='Sheet1'!A2
='Sheet1'!A3
```

Instead the formulas now read:

```
='Sheet1'!A2
='Sheet1'!A4
```

Where as it should keep the same formula and should read:

```
='Sheet1'!A2
='Sheet1'!A3
='Sheet1'!A4
```

Is there a way to correct this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation of what you are really looking for**

You are misunderstanding one of the cornerstones of how Excel deals with cell references.

Instead of thinking of each cell as simply a grid named by its row and column location, think of each cell as a unique piece of data. To start with, the top left cell (which we will give the unique ID cell1) is located at A1. This is its location, not its ID. If we insert a new column to the left of cell1, cell1 itself has moved along the grid. So now cell1 happens to be located at B1, instead of A1.

This is called a Direct reference - we are directly referring to a specific cell by saying ='Sheet1'!A2. It looks like we're saying "Pull the cell located at A2" but actually it means "when I first type this formula, find the unique ID of the cell currently located at A2. No matter how that cell moves around from rows or columns changing, always refer to that cell". Thus, the formulas move around as you've noticed.

To avoid this (and there are of course times as you've seen when we want to avoid this) you need to use an Indirect reference. An indirect reference is a way to permanently refer to a cell by its Grid location, instead of by its unique ID (there are other uses of indirect references which we will ignore).

**To do what you are asking** is as simple as saying:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A2")
```

No matter how Cell A2 moves around, this formula will always point exactly to that location based on the Grid, not the unique cell ID.

**EDIT to account for the fact that you actually have hundreds of cells to change**

You can actually build a formula into INDIRECT, which will reference a specific cell based on a calculation. Let's assume first that all your cells are in column A, and that you always want A1 in one sheet to refer to A1 in another sheet, and A5 to refer to A5. This would look as follows:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW())
```

ROW() gives you the row number of the formula which the cell is in. So in row 1, this becomes A1. In row 5, this becomes A5.

Now let's assume you want this in all cells from A1 to D500. Here, we obviously can't hardcode "A". So we will use the COLUMN() function much like the ROW() function above. However, note that COLUMN() returns the column *number*, where as we would normally refer to the column *letter*. This can be fixed 2 ways - either convert the number to a letter [which can be done, but is generally longer] or using the R1C1 reference style allowed by INDIRECT.

R1C1 is an alternative to the standard A1 method of referencing. R5C4 for example says: 'the cell 5 rows down and 4 cells to the right). So with the INDIRECT function, this would look like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN,FALSE)
```

By adding ",FALSE" to the back of INDIRECT, we are telling Excel to use the R1C1 method of referencing.

Comment: I tried this but missed the double quotes haha I have tried this and works well with the first few rows of data, however, this is a bit of a nightmare if you have, for example, 200 rows of data because you have to edit each formula individually

Comment: Okay I assumed you just had those cells - I will edit to show you the power of Indirect that I alluded to in the original response.

Comment: @tombannister See edited response which accounts for how to dynamically fix many cells, instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: That is brilliant, I never think to use the row as a cell reference. Although I has to make a slight edit to the formula to fit into my spreadsheet. On my second sheet the row that is showing the data is 5 rows below the data on the task list so instead I had to do this:  =INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW()-5) ...Perfect answer though, thank you for your help.

Comment: @tombannister Glad I could help - just be wary of overusing this, because INDIRECT is a volatile function, which means it recalculates whenever any cell changes (instead of just when a relevant cell changes) so it can be slower if you have too many (10,000s), and if you forget you're using it you might change some rows around and get an unintended result.

Comment: I have found another issue with the indirect function, when this is used and you have data at the side of this, the data at the side of this stays in place, it does not follow the data down if a row is added

Comment: @tombannister Well yes, all cells not using the indirect function will behave in Excel's default manner as I discuss above; in my opinion if you are overrelying on INDIRECT it is a sign that perhaps you should restructure your output so that it is able to follow Excel's normal behavour.